# Callback with Classie.js

Tags: javascript, callback

I'm using [Classie.JS](https://gist.github.com/desandro/4624426) to create a s[lideover menu demonstrated on Codrops](http://tympanus.net/Blueprints/SlidePushMenus/).

Part of the code I'm using is below. I'd like to implement a callback, so that the last 2 lines of this function only occur once the toggle has completed (it's animated). Thanks!

```
showLeftOpen.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
    $('#showLeftOpen').hide();
    $('#showLeftClose').show();
};
```

Answer (score 1):

The try/finally didn't work for me, so I just used a setTimeout() function to achieve the desired effect:

```
showLeftOpen.onclick = function() {
    classie.toggle( this, 'active' );
    classie.toggle( menuLeft, 'cbp-spmenu-open' );
    disableOther( 'showLeft' );
    setTimeout(function(){
              $('#showLeftOpen').hide();
              $('#showLeftClose').show();
    },200);
};
```